# R: Trying to replace values in one column with values in another column based on some conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, data-wrangling

So I have a a dataframe,df: `df = data.frame(c("",1,1),c(1,"",1),c(1,1,""))`

I want to loop through the dataframe and replace the values in the first and second column, if they are empty, with the value in the third column if it has a value in it:

```
n = nrow(df)
    for(i in 1:n)df[i,] <-{
    if(df[i,1] == "" & df[i,2] == "" & df[i,3] != ""){
    df[i,1] = df[i,3]
    df[i,2] = df[i,3]
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

`error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero.` I've been trying for quite some time, but can't figure our what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you may have used '&' when you should have been using '|'. There are no rows where `df[i,1] == "" & df[i,2] == ""`. Also there are no rows where both column values need to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since R is vectorized you do not need a loop:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("1", "1", "1"), B = c("1", "1", "1"), C = c("1", 
"1", "")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note your data are character vectors as in your example data. The answer will differ slightly if they are numeric.

```
df$A[df$A==""] <- df$C[df$A==""]
df$B[df$B==""] <- df$C[df$B==""]
df
#   A B C
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 1 1 1
# 3 1 1
```

Comment: Why am I overthinking stuff so much sometimes? I can just do this in a successive manner. I didn't clarify in my post, since I figure it would be easy once I got my loop to work. But I if values are missing in both col A and B, I want to replace both with values in column C. If only values are missing in Either Col A or B I want to replace it with whichever is not missing.

But your code works perfectly fine, I'll just run your code, and if they are still missing, I do another iteration where I replace the right-hand side with C. Thank you verry much!